# Set active cell when click on it in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have this component:

```
const arr = [];

const test = (date) => {
  arr.push(date);
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Space direction="vertical" size={12}>
    <DatePicker
      onChange={test}
      open={true}
      showNow={false}
      dateRender={(current) => {
        const style = {};
        if (arr.includes(current)) {
          style.border = "1px solid red";
          style.borderRadius = "50%";
        }
        return (
          <div className="ant-picker-cell-inner" style={style}>
            {current.date()}
          </div>
        );
      }}
    />
  </Space>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

The idea is next: when I click on the specific date it should be applied next styles:

```
if (arr.includes(current)) {
  style.border = "1px solid red";
  style.borderRadius = "50%";
}
```

I don't now why, but it does not work. I want when I will click on the date to apply these styles and when I click back on the same cell to deselect the styles, but my condition does not work. Who can help?

[Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/customized-date-rendering-antd494-forked-157er?file=/index.js:191-786).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that both `current` and the values pushed into `arr` are objects and not simple values. Objects can only be equal if they are reference equal.

```js
const foo1 = { a: 'bar' };
const foo2 = { a: 'bar' };
const foo3 = foo1;

console.log(foo1 === foo2); // false
console.log(foo2 === foo3); // false
console.log(foo1 === foo3); // true

console.log([foo1].includes(foo2)); // false
```

## Solution

You need to do an array search and do some value comparison. MomentJS date objects can be coerced to a number timestamp. Use [array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to compare each Moment object in the array to the current value, coercing each to the timestamp. If a matching Moment date object isn't found then `undefined` is returned and the condition is falsey.

```
dateRender={(current) => {
  const style = {};
  if (arr.find(date => +date === +current)) {
    style.border = "1px solid red";
    style.borderRadius = "50%";
  }
  return (
    <div className="ant-picker-cell-inner" style={style}>
      {current.date()}
    </div>
  );
}}
```

Note: this is simply one solution to convert the Moment date objects to a value that is easily comparable. Many others exist.

Comment: could you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65503806/fix-date-picker-inside-modal-window-in-react-js

Answer (score 1):

`onChange` event callback returns moment object as parameter, so `arr.includes(current)` will not work. You should convert the moment object into some kinda type which can be compared.

For the quick workaround, you can convert it into ISO string with `format()` function.

Also to implement deselection, you need to check if the clicked date is already added into the array.

```js
const test = (date) => {
  const str = date.format();
  if (arr.includes(str)) {
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(str), 1);
  } else {
    arr.push(str);
  }
};
```

```js
if (arr.includes(current.format())) {
```

Comment: could you help with this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65503806/fix-date-picker-inside-modal-window-in-react-js

Answer (score 0):

The Moment object which is getting pushed in `arr` differs for the `current` Moment object in `if(arr.includes(current))`. You can console and check they have different milliseconds.

Solutions

1. Write a method to check in array for current date by comparing day, month and year.
2. While pushing in arr simply date object which can be checked in the if condition by simplifying the current object. (Probably define push in array as a string in a particular format and use that format to check)