# Fix date picker inside modal window in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have this component:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const showModal = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(true);
  };

  const handleOk = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={showModal}>
        Open Modal
      </Button>
      <Modal
        title="Basic Modal"
        visible={isModalVisible}
        onOk={handleOk}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
      >
        <DatePicker
          onChange={test}
          open={true}
          showNow={false}
          dateRender={(current) => {
            const style = {};
            if (arr.includes(current)) {
              style.border = "1px solid red";
              style.borderRadius = "50%";
            }
            return (
              <div className="ant-picker-cell-inner" style={style}>
                {current.date()}
              </div>
            );
          }}
        />
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

When i open the modal i get the calendar outside it. How to put the calendar inside the modal window, not outside like now?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd494-forked-6lkqg?file=/index.js:269-1303

Comment: does the datepicker have to be opened always?

Comment: @baymax, yes it should be opened

Comment: @baymax, could you help?

Comment: setting `display: flex` for the modal style should improve it

Comment: @jamomani, like this?                 style={{display: "flex"}}
It does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, IMO, incredibly hackish, but was the only way I could get the date picker's popup to behave a bit more nicely nested in a modal.

1. Use the `getPopupContainer` prop to specify what the parent should be, it defaults to "body". We can create our own element to append the date popup to.
2. Use the `popupStyle` prop to override and set the `position` CSS rule. It is `position: absolute` by default, we wan't relative positioning.
3. Add an empty div after `DatePicker` for the popup to attach to.
4. ***HACK ALERT***: `DatePicker` inserts a div between the one we created and the popup, so CSS rule cascading & inheritance gets fubar'd, it has `position: absolute` as well. We need to override this to also use relative positioning.

Code:

```
<>
  <Button type="primary" onClick={showModal}>
    Open Modal
  </Button>
  <Modal
    title="Basic Modal"
    visible={isModalVisible}
    onOk={handleOk}
    onCancel={handleCancel}
  >
    <DatePicker
      getPopupContainer={() => document.getElementById("date-popup")}
      popupStyle={{
        position: "relative"
      }}
      onChange={test}
      open={true}
      showNow={false}
      dateRender={(current) => {
        const style = {};
        if (arr.includes(current)) {
          style.border = "1px solid red";
          style.borderRadius = "50%";
        }
        return (
          <div className="ant-picker-cell-inner" style={style}>
            {current.date()}
          </div>
        );
      }}
    />
    <div id="date-popup" />
  </Modal>
</>
```

CSS

```
#date-popup > div {
  position: relative !important;
}
```

[image]

The main reason this is hackish is because the use of `!important` should generally be avoided and instead you should strive to increase a selector's specificity. I was unable to bump it enough to override the style. (*I believe this is because that div is also using some inline `style` prop/attribute*)

[image: Edit fix-date-picker-inside-modal-window-in-react-js]

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker itself is also a kind of Modal so it can't be embedded inside Modal. You can simply check this by inspecting both Modal and DatePicker components.

If you want the DatePicker to be opened, you can control the height of modal body. Something like this.

```js
<Modal
  title="Basic Modal"
  visible={isModalVisible}
  onOk={handleOk}
  onCancel={handleCancel}
  bodyStyle={{
    height: 400
  }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another suggestion:

```
      <Modal
        title="Basic Modal"
        visible={isModalVisible}
        onOk={handleOk}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
        centered
        style={{ minHeight: `500px` }}
      >
```